# Row-based dynamic column subset mean in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a problem that can be visualized in the following way:

|  | Our | Cat | The | Home | They | Able |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 10 | 15 | NaN | 30 | 20 | 25 |
| Bob | 12 | NaN | 14 | 29 | NaN | 30 |
| John | NaN | 9 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 20 |
| Tyler | 11 | 12 | 13 | 24 | 25 | 26 |

In general, there is numeric data assigned to each person (index) in each column, but there are empty spaces.
I am wondering how to fill each NaN with the average for the same person for the *columns with the same name length* as the column with the missing value. In other words, how to combine `fillna()` and `mean()` with some custom logic for which columns are taken into consideration. The perfect result would be:

|  | Our | Cat | The | Home | They | Able |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 10 | 15 | **12.5** | 30 | 20 | 25 |
| Bob | 12 | **13** | 14 | 29 | **29.5** | 30 |
| John | **9** | 9 | **9** | **20** | **20** | 20 |
| Tyler | 11 | 12 | 13 | 24 | 25 | 26 |

With the numbers in bold being the averages for the same person for the same "column length".

Unfortunately, in my real life scenario there are hundreds of columns, so I cannot manually list the corresponding columns for each of them.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.map(len), axis =1).apply(lambda x: x.T.fillna(x.mean(1)).T)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
        Our   Cat   The  Home  They  Able
Alice  10.0  15.0  12.5  30.0  20.0  25.0
Bob    12.0  13.0  14.0  29.0  29.5  30.0
John    9.0   9.0   9.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
Tyler  11.0  12.0  13.0  24.0  25.0  26.0
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think you are misreading the question. The OP wants to fill in the Null values with the grouped mean based on the column name character length. For example, the length of Cat Our Dog is 3, so the grouped mean is 9 to be imputed (for those columns). Similarly, the other columns have a length of 4, so the grouped mean should be based on those, to fill the Nulls in those columns.

Comment: @sophocles Ohh yes!!. you're correct!!. I was misreading the question. Thanks :) Will try to fix the answer.

Comment: This seems to be much faster than my answer with larger amounts of data; nicely done! +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working:

```
# create a df to hold the per-person means for each column name length
meandf = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns, dtype=float)

# find the unique column name lengths
lengths = set(len(i) for i in df.columns)

# iterate over the lengths and find take the mean for that chunk of the df
for l in lengths:
    subsetcols = df.columns[[len(col) == l for col in df.columns]]
    personmeans = df.loc[:, subsetcols].mean(axis=1)
    meandf.loc[personmeans.index, subsetcols] = personmeans

# write to the original df
df[df.isna()] = meandf
```

Result:

```
>>> df
        Our   Cat   The  Home  They  Able
Alice  10.0  15.0  12.5  30.0  20.0    25
Bob    12.0  13.0  14.0  29.0  29.5    30
John    9.0   9.0   9.0  20.0  20.0    20
Tyler  11.0  12.0  13.0  24.0  25.0    26
```

I used `meandf` as intermediate structure for holding the means (I couldn't figure out the indexing without it).  In each cell, it contains the mean for each person for each column name length:

```
>>> meandf
        Our   Cat   The  Home  They  Able
Alice  12.5  12.5  12.5  25.0  25.0  25.0
Bob    13.0  13.0  13.0  29.5  29.5  29.5
John    9.0   9.0   9.0  20.0  20.0  20.0
Tyler  12.0  12.0  12.0  25.0  25.0  25.0
```